# How to reuse data from one addplot table for plotting in another axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Is there anyway to reuse the data of a `\addplot table` for plotting in another `axis` environment?

I would like to avoid putting the data into a separate file. Is there any way to refer to the data in a table for plotting?

Something like: (It cannot compile)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=5cm,
height=5cm,
scale only axis,
enlargelimits=false,
line join=round
]
\addplot [color=white!70!black,solid,line width=0.5pt,forget plot]
  table[name=tab1,row sep=crcr]{
1   -1  \\
2   -2  \\
3   3   \\
4   4   \\
};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
width=5cm,
height=5cm,
scale only axis,
enlargelimits=false,
line join=round
]
\addplot [color=red,solid,line width=0.8pt,forget plot]
table[name=tab1]{tab1};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `pgfplotstable` facilities to read and hold it in a macro

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}%<== Loads pgfplots anyway
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=crcr]{
1   -1  \\
2   -2  \\
3   3   \\
4   4   \\
}\mytable

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=5cm,
height=5cm,
scale only axis,
enlargelimits=false,
line join=round
]
\addplot [color=black!30,solid,line width=1pt,forget plot]
  table {\mytable};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
width=5cm,
height=5cm,
scale only axis,
enlargelimits=false,
line join=round,at={(7cm,0)}
]
\addplot [color=red,solid,line width=0.5pt,forget plot]
table {\mytable};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

[image]